# why javafxpackager -could not load main class?

Tags: javafx, program-entry-point, packager

I have a silly question since I've searched the databse here but I couldn't find the answer. I'm new to javaFX and all so ... please help me out!.

Here's the code I used. It's a sample code though.

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

After compiling it from within the directory .\helloworld using `javac HelloWorld.java`, I run the following command:

`PS D:\documents\javafx\helloworld> javafxpackager -createjar -appclass HelloWorld -srcdir . -outdir out -outfile hello.jar -v`

But then, when I `cd` to `out` and run `java -jar hello.jar` I get this:

`PS D:\documents\javafx\helloworld\out> java -jar hello.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`

What happened or did I do something wrong?

Any suggestion/explanation is really appreciated.

Thanks all.

Zestos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application class is in package helloworld, so to reference it you should use the fully qualified name of helloworld.HelloWorld.

Here is a complete example using the example HelloWorld application from your question.  I tried this on OS X 10.8 with Oracle Java 8u25 installed and it worked for me.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25

$ tree 
.
├── classes
└── src
    └── helloworld
        └── HelloWorld.java

3 directories, 1 file

$ javac -d classes src/helloworld/HelloWorld.java

$ tree
.
├── classes
│   └── helloworld
│       ├── HelloWorld$1.class
│       └── HelloWorld.class
└── src
    └── helloworld
        └── HelloWorld.java

4 directories, 3 files

$/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javapackager -createjar -appclass helloworld.HelloWorld -srcdir classes -outdir dist -outfile hello.jar -v

$ tree
.
├── classes
│   └── helloworld
│       ├── HelloWorld$1.class
│       └── HelloWorld.class
├── dist
│   └── hello.jar
└── src
    └── helloworld
        └── HelloWorld.java

5 directories, 4 files

$ java -jar dist/hello.jar
```

Comment: I've tried the command you typed above both inside and outside the folder helloworld but I still got the error above.
I also used `javapackager` but to no avail.
Any idea why?

Comment: I do not know why things do not work for you.  I just copied the command from your question and fixed the app class specifier.  Try this [helloworld packaging sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5018976)

Comment: I added a complete log to this answer of the steps I took to compile and run the program.

Comment: I traced back the steps and realized that I've put my `-outdir` within the `-srcdir` and thus preventing me from calling the `hello.jar` in its proper way. Thank you very much for your help.